# Change color font only in part of textview

Tags: android, colors, fonts, textview, spannable

i want to change only a part of textview color.. I've tried in this way but nothing change

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Temperature);
textView.setText("Temperature: "+ "<small> <font color='#59c3fa'>" + temperature + "°C</font></small>");
```

So the first part `"Temperature: "` has to have the textview color (Black in this case), and the rest of part with this `#59c3fa`. How is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Please use `Html` class for this.

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Temperature: "+ "<small> <font color='#59c3fa'>" + temperature + "°C</font></small>"));
```

Comment: Works perfectly thank you. I've only change `Html.from` to `Html.fromHtml`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```
String text = "Temperature: "+ "<small> <font color='#59c3fa'>" + temperature + "°C</font></small>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Temperature);
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Temperature: "+ "<small> <font color='#59c3fa'>" + temperature + "°C</font></small>"));
```